# Macro to run specific Run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, macros, pycharm

I have several `Run configuration`'s in PyCharm:

- one is for celery
- second is for restarting rabbit
- third is for main script run

Do not ask me why I need these configurations, I just want to use 3 shortcuts to run three `Run configuration`'s separately.

So I decided to create macros for each one. But macro does not record choosing specific `Run configuration`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Macro

1. Open the run configurations menu (`F10` in my setup)
2. Type the name of the config to run
3. Press enter

### [image: Run config pycharm macro]

### Bug on Mac OS

Not sure who could be impacted, but I ran into an annoying bug on the old macbook I'm hanging on to: Pycharm correctly receives each key at recording time (as can be seen in the macro window). But when replaying, instead of inputing the chars it seems to 'type' using my keyboard layout (BÉPO, french), using QWERTY locations !

**Workaround:**

1. Switch your computer to QWERTY
2. Run the macro recording
3. Type the config name as with your **usual** keyboard
4. Press enter (although the run config window will probably no longer be showing anything)
5. Stop recording
6. Switch back to your usual keyboard

For my example, my *working* macro is saying `Typing: "ka;iqrc"` !

Comment: Jeez this is [an old bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-27262) .. I had noticed weird things sometimes indeed, but not as bad as this. Anyway, only seems to be for mac users.

Answer (score 0):

I've created plugin to be able to use shortcuts to execute Run/Debug Configurations: [Run Configuration as Action](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action).
After loading of this plugin it register all Run/Debug configurations as actions. So you can assign shortcut for them, add them to toolbars, etc.
[image]

It works for all Jetbrains IDEs based on IntelliJ platform: CLion, PyCharm, PhpStorm, etc.